# Issue on TextFragment.Margin with justify

Tags: aspose, aspose.pdf

I have an requirement to apply the indent and justify the paragraph text, so I have applied the margin for the TextFragment and applied the justify property. But the right side text was went to out of the page and showed like a trimmed some text on right side.

If I used table cell and apply the margin for cell and justify the cell text it is working but page size was increased and performance was decreased so we are not recommended for table approach.

Below is my code snippet.

```
        Document pdfDoc = new Document();
        pdfDoc.PageInfo.Width = 612.0;
        pdfDoc.PageInfo.Height = 792.0;
        pdfDoc.PageInfo.Margin = new MarginInfo();
        pdfDoc.PageInfo.Margin.Left = 72;
        pdfDoc.PageInfo.Margin.Right = 72;
        pdfDoc.PageInfo.Margin.Top = 72;
        pdfDoc.PageInfo.Margin.Bottom = 72;

        Page pdfPage = pdfDoc.Pages.Add();
        pdfPage.PageInfo.Width = 612.0;
        pdfPage.PageInfo.Height = 792.0;
        pdfPage.PageInfo.Margin = new MarginInfo();
        pdfPage.PageInfo.Margin.Left = 72;
        pdfPage.PageInfo.Margin.Right = 72;
        pdfPage.PageInfo.Margin.Top = 72;
        pdfPage.PageInfo.Margin.Bottom = 72;

        TextFragment textfragment = new TextFragment("This line for verify the indent");
        textfragment.TextState.FontSize = 12;
        textfragment.TextState.Font = Aspose.Pdf.Text.FontRepository.FindFont("Arial");
        textfragment.TextState.LineSpacing = 15;
        pdfPage.Paragraphs.Add(textfragment);

        textfragment = new TextFragment("TextFragment with Justify : This AGREEMENT AND PLAN OF MERGER (this \"Agreement\") is made and entered into as of ______ __, ____, by and among ___________________, a Delaware corporation (\"Parent\"),___________________, a Delaware corporation and a wholly owned subsidiary of Parent (\"MergerSub\"), and ___________________, a Delaware corporation (the \"Company\").");
        textfragment.TextState.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Justify;
        textfragment.TextState.FontSize = 12;
        textfragment.TextState.Font = Aspose.Pdf.Text.FontRepository.FindFont("Arial");
        textfragment.TextState.LineSpacing = 15;
        //for ss_indent I have given 10f left indent into text fragment.
        textfragment.Margin = new MarginInfo(10f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        pdfPage.Paragraphs.Add(textfragment);

        textfragment = new TextFragment("TextFragment without Justify : This AGREEMENT AND PLAN OF MERGER (this \"Agreement\") is made and entered into as of ______ __, ____, by and among ___________________, a Delaware corporation (\"Parent\"),___________________, a Delaware corporation and a wholly owned subsidiary of Parent (\"MergerSub\"), and ___________________, a Delaware corporation (the \"Company\").");
        textfragment.TextState.FontSize = 12;
        textfragment.TextState.Font = Aspose.Pdf.Text.FontRepository.FindFont("Arial");
        textfragment.TextState.LineSpacing = 15;
        //for ss_indent I have given 10f left indent into text fragment.
        textfragment.Margin = new MarginInfo(10f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        pdfPage.Paragraphs.Add(textfragment);
```

Please suggest me if it have any other way to do this requirement.

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: Hi, my name is Nayyer and I am developer Evangelist at Aspose.
I have tested the scenario and have managed to reproduce the same issue (PDFNEWNET-39105). We request you to please post the query in Aspose.Pdf product support forum, so that we can associate the issue ID with forum thread and once this problem is resolved, you will get an automatic intimation.

Comment: Thank you Nayyer. I have logged the issue in aspose, below is the link : http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/644497/issue-on-textfragment.margin-with-justify/showthread.aspx#644497.